# Javascript NaN value after form validation

Tags: javascript

I have the following part of a function which adds event and delivery totals together:

```
    // IF currentElement is radio AND currentElement is checked
    if (currentElement.type == "radio" && currentElement.checked) {

        // Parse into a number (as a float)
        deliveryTotal = deliveryTotal + parseFloat(currentElement.title);

    }


    // IF currentElement is a checkbox AND currentElement is checked
    else if (currentElement.type == "checkbox" && currentElement.checked) {

        // Parse into a number (as a float)
        eventTotal = eventTotal + parseFloat(currentElement.title);

    }

}

// Assign total to input with "£" infront - to 2 decimal places
totalbox.value = "£" + (eventTotal + deliveryTotal).toFixed(2);
```

This seems to work fine until i validate my form for example, displaying an alert, when after it just returns the value "£ NaN",

I believe this has something to do with the `parseFloat` part of my function, could someone kindly advise as to what may be causing this value.

Comment: And what is the title you're parsing into a float ?

Comment: Either the deliveryTotal and/or eventTotal have not been initialised to zero or the currentElement.title is not a numeric value

Comment: The title is a price for example "10.99".

Comment: I will advise you for using some debugging tool to help here. There are options for most popular browsers out there, some built in in the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Number() instead of parseFloat().
In case you have an empty string, this will return zero.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number

Answer (score 0):

`parseFloat` will take some strings with non-number characters and not others.  To fully understand what is accepted and what is not, [see here for documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) regarding the method `parseFloat`.

However in my experience, more often than not, the value isn't what you expect it to be.  My advice is to check the values `currentElement.title`, `deliveryTotal`, and `eventTotal` upon entry into the function and see what values they hold.  If you still don't see a smoking gun, evaluate everything that gets calculated in your function one at a time in your browser console and see what it returns.

That's just my 10 cents though.  :)